# iproute2 routing through multiple networks with rt_tables

Tags: routing, iproute2

This question is similar to many others I've consulted while seeking an answer, both on ServerFault and elsewhere, but I'm stuck because as far as I can see I've set this up correctly but I'm have no joy getting it working.

I've set up a simulated environment using multiple machine in VirtualBox, one represents a server (to be used as a router) the other simulates two ADSL modems (just behaves as a NAT router with two ports on LAN side and one on WAN side to internet).

The server (SRV) connects two ports (ETH2 and ETH3) to two separate Vbox virtual networks through to the ADSL machine (connecting to it's ETH2/3 ports respectively).

```
                  +----------+
                  |   SRV    |
                  +----------+
 ETH2 (192.168.1.10) |     | ETH3 (192.168.2.11)
                     |     |
                     |     |
  ETH2 (192.168.1.1) |     | ETH3 (192.168.2.1)
                  +----------+
                  |   ADSL   |
                  +----------+
```

ADSL ports are ETH2 (192.168.1.1) and ETH3 (192.168.2.1).

SRV ports are ETH2 (192.168.1.10) and ETH3 (192.168.2.11).

SRV `iptables` do nothing of interest, besides see comments below on tweaks to `main` default route during testing.

---

## Setup

`ip route show`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth2
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.10
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.11
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.1
192.168.13.0/24 dev admin.tinc proto kernel scope link src 192.168.13.1
```

Set up two tables `adsl1` and `ads2`

`ip route show table adsl1`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth2
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth2 scope link src 192.168.1.10
```

`ip route show table adsl2`

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth3
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth3 scope link src 192.168.2.11
```

`ip rule`

```
0:      from all lookup local
32762:  from all to 192.168.1.0/24 lookup adsl1
32763:  from all to 192.168.2.0/24 lookup adsl2
32764:  from 192.168.2.0/24 lookup adsl2
32765:  from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup adsl1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

---

## Demonstrate issue

If I ping via ETH2, no problem.

`ping -I eth2 -c 1 google.com`

```
PING google.com (216.58.214.14) from 192.168.1.10 eth2: 56(84) bytes of 
data.
64 bytes from lhr26s05-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.214.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 
time=20.2 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.288/20.288/20.288/0.000 ms
```

If I ping via ETH3, no traffic on ETH3 at all.

```
PING google.com (216.58.213.110) from 192.168.2.11 eth3: 56(84) bytes of 
data.

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

If I change the `main` table default gateway...

`ip route replace default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth3`

the reverse occurs (ETH3 works, ETH2 fails). To my mind this suggests the routing tables `adsl1` and `adsl2` are either wrong or simply not being consulted (rules are wrong). But I can't figure out why?

---

## Update 1

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0`

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth2.rp_filter=0`

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth2.rp_filter=0`

Repeated `ping -I eth3 google.com` while...

`tcpdump -i eth3`

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:26:32.207178 ARP, Request who-has lhr35s11-in-f14.1e100.net tell 192.168.2.11, length 28
20:26:33.221587 ARP, Request who-has lhr35s11-in-f14.1e100.net tell 192.168.2.11, length 28
```

---

## Additional info to update 1

When ETH3 is set as default route in `main` (no other changes) the `tcpdump` is:

```
tcpdump: listening on eth3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
21:41:51.865488 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 31173, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    192.168.2.11 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 2962, seq 1, length 64
21:41:51.866542 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 18679, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    192.168.2.11.36067 > one.one.one.one.domain: [bad udp cksum 0xc4f9 -> 0xb220!] 31965+ PTR? 11.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa. (43)
21:41:51.885947 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 61, id 4776, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    google-public-dns-a.google.com > 192.168.2.11: ICMP echo reply, id 2962, seq 1, length 64
```

---

### Addition to additional info

`ip route get 8.8.8.8 oif eth3`

```
8.8.8.8 dev eth3 src 192.168.2.11
    cache  users 1
```

So definitely something damaged with routing (rather than problems elsewhere). Also explains the singular presence of `ARP`!

**Okay!**

I seems that when traffic is directed to interface ETH3 it is not assigned a 'from' address of `192.168.2.11` as I expect, at least not in time for the routing policy db decision.

I manually added a simple rule:

`ip rule add to 8.8.8.8 lookup adsl2`

Then

`ip route get 8.8.8.8 oif eth3`

```
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.2.1 dev eth3 table adsl2 src 192.168.2.11
    cache
```

Evidently table `adsl2` is being used and correctly sets the `via 192.168.2.1`. Hurrah!

**BUT** if I replace that rule with the more specific rule

`ip rule add to 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.2.11 lookup adsl2`

I get

`ip route get 8.8.8.8 oif eth3`

```
8.8.8.8 dev eth3 src 192.168.2.11
    cache
```

Back to state where `via` not being set, conclusion: `adsl2` table not being used. Further conclusion: `from` not effective, so interface `eth3` not setting src address to `192.168.2.11` despite `ip a` showing

```
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e5:7e:eb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.11/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth3
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee5:7eeb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Where have I screwed up?

Comment: Is `rp_filter` disabled?  Have you tried doing a tcpdump and verifying that packets are being sent via the interface you expect?

Comment: @Zoredache `rp_filter` is enabled (1). Did not capture `tcpdump`, but monitored the relevant interface with `iftop`

Comment: The rp_filter must be disabled when using the route policy features.  If you haven't tried capturing, then try it now.  See what is going on.  Verify that things are working they way you should.  Look at the various headers of the IP backets source/dest, ports etc.  Are they leaving via the correct interface.  Are you seeing replies at all, or from the wrong interface, etc.

Comment: Disables `rp_filter` (I actually changed `/etc/sysctl.conf` an rebooted to be sure. Then flushed the `iptables` to make sure they where clean. `fially did test and have updated my question : **Update 1**

Comment: Its odd, your tcpdump you are showing seems to see both the ping request and reply..

Comment: Yes, but only when the interface is also on the default route in `main`. When it's only the default route in the `adsl2` table I get only the `ARP` packets (see end of update 1--the 'proper'' configuration-- rather than the additional info where I added the default route to main).

Comment: @Zoredache I've added some more detail following my recent experiments/investigation. I'm still confused as to exactly what's going on but I have narrowed down  the problem a little.